# react localStorage empty array and null on first rendering

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, persist

I try to get used with localStorage and I run into something I'm confused with.

1. When I try to add the first task at the localStorage it doesn't save the task object however just an empty array and only then after adding the second task, it starts to save the object task ?
2. Since that my first point somehow isn't working correctly the second issue is that now when I clean up manually the localStorage and refresh the page I run into a null error that occurs.

Here is the code below if someone can give me some insight about it. Thank you

```
const SearchInput = () => {
  const [taskValue, setTaskValue] = useState("");
  const [allTasks, setAllTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const persistedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
    setAllTasks(persistedTasks);
    console.log(persistedTasks);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTaskValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (taskValue !== "") {
      setAllTasks([
        ...allTasks,
        { id: allTasks.length + 1, text: taskValue.trim() },
      ]);
    }
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(allTasks));
    setTaskValue("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add a task..."
          value={taskValue}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button>Submit the Task</button>
      </Form>
      <TasksContainer>
        {!allTasks.length && <p>No tasks</p>}
        {!!allTasks.length && (
          <ul>
            {allTasks.map((task) => (
              <TaskWrapper key={task.id}>
                <li>{task.text} </li>
                <div>
                  <button>Edit</button>
                  <button>Delete</button>
                </div>
              </TaskWrapper>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </TasksContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: in what? A regular browser? A headless browser like Selenium? An Electron app? A mobile native webview? Something else?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans : on the browser actually.

Comment: your useEffect will run once the component is rendered . So for a fraction of a second your allTasks will be empty array . If you want your initialState to be the value from localStorage then you can do lazy initialisation . `const [ .... ] = useState(() => json.parse(localStorage....) || [])`

Comment: @mugi, remember to [put that in your post](/help/how-to-ask).